# Issue when running script on Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script

Google docs state that the script is running but nothing happens.  There is also an error code that states:  Service not found: plus v1.

```
 function fillSelected() {

      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var OpName = sheet.getRange("K3:K3").getValues();  

      sheet.getRange('E7:E8').setValue(OpName);
      sheet.getRange('E10:E10').setValue(OpName);
      sheet.getRange('E12:E14').setValue(OpName);
      sheet.getRange('E16:E17').setValue(OpName);
      sheet.getRange('E19:E20').setValue(OpName);
      sheet.getRange('E22:E23').setValue(OpName);
      sheet.getRange('I7:I8').setValue(OpName);
      sheet.getRange('I10:I12').setValue(OpName);
      sheet.getRange('I14:I16').setValue(OpName);
      sheet.getRange('I18:I19').setValue(OpName);     
      sheet.getRange('I21:I21').setValue(OpName);
      sheet.getRange('I23:I23').setValue(OpName);
      sheet.getRange('I23:I23').setValue(OpName);
      sheet.getRange('J28').setValue(OpName);
      //sheet.getRange('J31').setValue(OpName);
      //sheet.getRange('J34').setValue(OpName);
}
```

Comment: Did you check in the execution transcripts section? Your code is running fine without any errors. `Service not found: plus v1.` is something related to Google Plus, this might be used by the script to fetch user profile. Do you have any such code in the project?
If you don't know then try reauthorizing the script, To do that you need to revoke the script access first. Please go to https://myaccount.google.com/permissions, find your project and revoke the permission. After that go to the project and try the code again. You may get a different or more informative error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Sheets Scripts suddenly stop working - Error: "Service not found: plus v1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60467021/google-sheets-scripts-suddenly-stop-working-error-service-not-found-plus-v1)

Comment: check your Apps Script [manifest.json](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests#editing_a_manifest) from within the Script, verify you are not using deprecated Google Plus service. If so, remove it, since Google Plus v1 is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function fillSelected() {

  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var OpName = sheet.getRange("K3").getValue();  

  sheet.getRange('E7:E8').setValue(OpName);
  sheet.getRange('E10').setValue(OpName);
  sheet.getRange('E12:E14').setValue(OpName);
  sheet.getRange('E16:E17').setValue(OpName);
  sheet.getRange('E19:E20').setValue(OpName);
  sheet.getRange('E22:E23').setValue(OpName);
  sheet.getRange('I7:I8').setValue(OpName);
  sheet.getRange('I10:I12').setValue(OpName);
  sheet.getRange('I14:I16').setValue(OpName);
  sheet.getRange('I18:I19').setValue(OpName);     
  sheet.getRange('I21').setValue(OpName);
  sheet.getRange('J28').setValue(OpName);
```

Comment: Thank you for all the replies.  Where would I go to find the manifest.json?

Comment: In your script editor  it's named appsscript.json.  Look in the View menu and check view Manifest.