# Error: "Service not found: plus v1" on running any script in a project. How to resolve?

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I built a Google Sheets document that has lots of scripts and triggers built into it.

It worked for the last year flawlessly until recently. Now every Function does not work, even for other users. Even simple functions does not work.

When I try to run any script, I get this message: *"Service not found: plus v1"*

What is interesting is that another google sheet file that uses much of the same coding still works perfectly.

I also get a message: *"This project is running on our new Apps Script runtime powered by Chrome V8".* I am not sure if that has anything to do with it or not.

I did a search on the Scripts and found this code on a new tab called appsscript.json

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Denver",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
      "userSymbol": "Plus",
      "serviceId": "plus",
      "version": "v1"
    }, {
      "userSymbol": "Drive",
      "serviceId": "drive",
      "version": "v2"
    }]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

I do not know what this code is for and I dont recall writing it. Can I safely delete it?

Comment: Do you have any functions using Google+? Or is plus enabled in Resources> Advanced Google services?

Comment: @TheMaster I believe the Answer is No, and no. The only thing enabled in Resources>Advanced Google Services is "Drive API".

Comment: Any Global variables outside any functions? Any libraries?Resources>libraries

Comment: This is the [plus service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/plus) and some script is using it to identify you or other users.

Comment: @TheMaster No, No Libraries. Id be happy to link it if needed. What is interesting is another sheet with almost the same functions is working fine... And this one was working perfectly for a year with no changes done to it.

Comment: @TheMaster See Edit. I found a piece of Code that contains possibly the "Plus Service"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You or anyone with edit access to your script has enabled a deprecated service - in this case, Google [plus service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/plus). This service is deprecated and shutdown. In new editor,

- Click settings icon >>> Show manifest "appsscript.json".
- And the file will be visible in code "Files" tab
- You can modify the manifest, appsscript.json to remove the offending advanced service from `enabledAdvancedServices` array.

#### Modified Manifest:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Denver",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
      "userSymbol": "Drive",
      "serviceId": "drive",
      "version": "v2"
    }]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

This block is removed:

```
{
      "userSymbol": "Plus",
      "serviceId": "plus",
      "version": "v1"
},
```